# how to sort a List based on the form order in another List

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Lists with two different Objects
List abc = new List(); and each Object has fields like ID, Name and City.
Another List contains List mno = new List(); and each object contains ID, FormOrder.

Like: List1

```
ID     Name     City
===================
205   AAAA    XXX
------------------
101   NNN    YYYY
------------------
105   CBC    NNN
------------------
25    NAN    CAP
=================


List2:

ID    FormOrder
=============
101     0
-------------
205     3
-------------
105     5
-------------
25      6
=============
```

Need to sort first List based on second list form order. any suggestions please.

Comment: You can also use l1.include(l2).orderby(l2.formorder) so no join may be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try applying LINQ join on both the lists based on the ID then sort the outcome based on FormOrder.

something like below,

```
var res = from l1 in list1 
          join l2 in list2 
          on l1.ID equals l2.ID 
          orderby l2.FormOrder
          select l1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.Join`, and join the first to the second.

```
list2.Join(list1, 
           l2 => l2.Id, 
           l1 => l1.Id, 
           (l1,l2) => new { l2.Id, l2.FormOrder, l1.Name, l1.City })
      .OrderBy(x=>x.FormOrder);
```